# imagick: Cannot get setImageBackgroundColor, setImageCompressionQuality and setImageResolution to work when creating images from PDF pages

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm having a problem when im trying to convert a PDF to images with imagick and PHP (5.5). everything works fine i can create a image for each page in the PDF but i run into the following problems. and have been stuck here for days now.

1. When i create a image from a PDF file some of them gets a black background even thou i have set setImageBackgroundColor to white
2. I have tried to set setImageCompressionQuality to get the image in better quality (right not the created image gets pixelated).
3. also i cannot seem to change the DPI version of the image to a 72 dpi one.

the code is as following:

```
    $file_name = basename($file_name);
    $img = new imagick();

    $img->readImage($dir.'/'.$file_name);
    $img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');

    $img->setResolution(72,72);
    $img->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);
    $img->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
    $img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    $img->stripImage();

    $num_pages = $img->getNumberImages();
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++) {
        $img->setIteratorIndex($i);

        $img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
        $img->flattenImages();
        $img->setImageFormat("jpeg");

        $final_name     = str_replace(" ", "+", basename(str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $file_name)));
        $final_name     = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-+]/", "", $final_name);

        $save_to        = $pdf_dir."/".str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $final_name).'-'.$i.'.jpg';

        $img->writeImage($save_to);

        $file_image = str_replace(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../", "/", $save_to);
        $file_images[] = $file_image;
    }
    $img->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mistakes in your code.

- setResolution needs to be called before loading the PDF
- You need to use setBackgroundColor rather than setImageBackgroundColor.
- You probably want to set the individual page compression quality, but see below.

So code:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(72, 72);

$imagick->readImage($file_name);
$imagick->setBackgroundColor('white');
$imagick->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(70);

foreach ($imagick as $c => $_page) {
    $_page->setBackgroundColor('white');
    $_page->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
    $_page->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $_page->writeImage($file."_background-$c.jpg");
}
```

btw, the fact that you're using JPEG at 100 quality is disturbing. If that is an image that is going to be sent to a browser, the quality should be lower than 100. If you are using it as an intermediate picture, using PNG as the intermediate format is better as it is lossless and it supports transparency.

Answer (score 0):

That seemed to do the trick, changed to answer a bit as i couldnt get your foreach to work thou, wich made it work as intended:
Thank you for saving me from alot of headache.

```
$img = new imagick();
$img->setResolution(72, 72);

$img->readImage($dir.'/'.$file_name);
$img->setBackgroundColor('white');
$img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(70);

$num_pages = $img->getNumberImages();
for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++) {
    $final_name     = str_replace(" ", "+", basename(str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $file_name)));
    $final_name     = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-+]/", "", $final_name);

    $save_to        = $pdf_dir."/".str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $final_name).'-'.$i.'.jpg';

    $img->setIteratorIndex($i);

    $img->setBackgroundColor('white');
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
    $img->setImageFormat('jpg');

    $img->writeImage($save_to);

    $file_image = str_replace(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../", "/", $save_to);
    $file_images[] = $file_image;
}
```